# Wix Toolset how to copy to folder with version in path

Tags: c#, msbuild, wix, post-build-event

I'm using Wix toolset v 3.11 in VS2019 to create a setup for our application. In order to ease maintenance, I need to copy the installer files to a folder with the version in its path.

Basically what I thought was to use a post build event where I would copy the files to a `\$(BootstrapPackageVersion)\$(Configuration)\` directory, but I am not able to find such variable.

I tried to extract the version from the .exe package (since it gets its version from the MSI package that itself get its version from the original application, as intended) with the following code in the .wixproj file:

```
  </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersions" />
        </GetAssemblyIdentity>
        <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetDir)/%(AssemblyVersions.Version)/">
            <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="CustomTargetName" />
        </CreateProperty>
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)/*" DestinationFolder="$(CustomTargetName)"/>
    </Target>
```

But it fails with the following error:

> Cannot get assembly name for "[Path]\Setup.exe". Could not load file
> or assembly 'Setup.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was
> expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I saw that there is a property, `$(WixBundleVersion)`, but it doesn't seems to be available to use in build events.

Basically what I want to achieve is a fairly simple thing: take the output from the bootstrapper project and copy everything to another path that include the package version. It is possible?

Comment: May point you in the right direction: I had issues getting the version from an exe, so instead of getting it from the setup.exe or myapp.exe I gather that from the .dll file. in dotnet core it usually builds myapp.exe and myapp.dll and myapp.dll will have the assembly version.

Comment: Yeah, referencing the original project would give me everything I need, but I wanted to remain within project boundaries as possible, also it baffles me that there is no way to retrieve the version at build time!

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this in my wix project is to output setup.exe into it's default folder and then run an `AfterBuild` and copy it to the final artifacts directory

in wixproj:

```
<Target>
...
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="..\MyApp.App\bin\$(Configuration)\net5.0\FrameworkDep\win-$(Platform)\Publish\MyApp.App.dll">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DefineConstants>BuildVersion=%(AssemblyVersion.Version)</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
...
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\en-us\$(OutputName).msi" DestinationFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName)_%(AssemblyVersion.Version).msi" />
</Target>
```

This assigns
`BuildVersion` which you can then use in your wxs files
and
`AssemblyVersion` which you can use in the wixproj with `%(AssemblyVersion.Version)`

the `AfterBuild` section is copying the msi to
`MyApp_1.2.3.msi`

in my wxs file I can use:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="My App" Language="1033" 
       Version="$(var.BuildVersion)>
```

This is then using the build version from above so I just version control MyApp.App project.

Comment: Thank you Smith, But I am working with the bootstrapper (I need to check if there is .net and other stuff before installing). I managed to carry the msi version inside the bootstrapped exe, but then apparently there is no "fairly simple" way to get the bootstrapped version to use like I would with other MSBuild variables...

Comment: That make sense. I wonder if having a small script pre-build/mid-build that goes and collects needed versions and puts them in environmental variables, then you could use them throughout the build process. You are right though, "fairly simple" never comes to mind when working on wix